# Domain of functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The example in my math text book has this explanation:

$g(x) =  \sqrt{x+3}$ where
$[-3, \infty)$ is the domain of this function.

Why is $-3$ part of the domain?

Comment: Because $\sqrt{0}$ is well defined

Comment: Is 0 the lowest possible answer for a sq root?

Comment: @thejdah yes, this is correct!

Answer (score 2):

This is because $\sqrt x$ is defined for $x\ge 0$

[image]

and thus $\sqrt {g(x)}$ is defined for $g(x)\ge 0$.

In this case

$$\sqrt {x+3} \implies x+3\ge0 \iff x\ge -3$$

Otherwise

$$h(x) =  \sqrt{\frac1{x+3}}$$ is defined for $x>-3$.

Comment: If the 3 was replaced with a 4, would the domain then included a -4?

Comment: yes in general for $\sqrt {x+a}$ the domain is given by $$x+a\ge 0\iff x\ge -a$$